# Magento select category not working without index.php in url

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I am using `Magento 1.9.1` for creating my store, I have installed it and added categories and products into it. Suppose my store URL is like the following:

```
http//:www.storename.com
```

When I click to a category from my site it is redirecting to `http//:www.storename.com/categoryname` . But I am getting a page with `404 error`. When I manually edit the page as `http//:www.storename.com/index.php/categoryname`, then it is working. I don't know what is the error happening in back end. I am new to `Magento` any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to System >> Configuration.
2. Click on Web (under General tab).
3. Under **Search Engine Optimization**, change value of **Use Web Server Rewrites** to **No**
4. Clear cache and reload the page.
   Now every thing should be working fine.

Note: If your web server is configured to read magento's .htaccess file, then you can also set mod_rewrite to yes without following above procedure.

This will remove index.php from URLs.

Comment: it is working now and 404 error is not coming. But index.php is coming along with those URLs. Any idea buddy?

Comment: To remove index.php from URL, your magento's .htaccess file must be readable by apache server. You need to check whether mod_rewrite is enabled on your server or not.

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled!

Comment: you can follow instructions from this URL to remove index.php:

http://www.indianwebportal.com/remove-index-php-url-magento